# Implementation of CDC mapping other than using mapping variable.

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I implemented CDC mapping using mapping variable.
to pass SETMAXVARIABLE($$CDC_DT, LAST_UPDATED_DATE) to the variable
and write the condition in source qualifier like where LAST_UPDATED_DATE>$$CDC_DT
as of now it is running fine, is there any other approach to implement the same. can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most effective way to implement CDC using mapping a variable, I have implemented and used it for years. The other methods will/might use a table/file to keep LAST_UPDATED_DATE, but it adds one more thing can go wrong.

The mapping variable method you have used has LAST_UPDATED_DATE kept in the repository, there is no additional maintenance of the last date.

One thing to keep in mind is when you migrate the mapping from one environment to another you need to remember to reset or assign an appropriate value to it. Same applies if you need to re-load data.

Comment: Thank you Mdem. I am using LAST_UPDATED_DATE>$$CDC_DT only  greater than not equal to . Is there chance of missing any transactions that happened in fraction of seconds? Please suggest

Comment: instead of LAST_UPDATED_DATE column can I use SESSSTARTTIME like setmaxvariable($$CDC_DT,SESSSTARTTIME ) which one should I take? could you please suggest.

Comment: Always use a column from source system, if you use equal to you'll get duplicate data, unless your source system creates lots of data in a second greater than  should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Theoretically this will work but then how will you recover data when some error condition causes you not to pick up records?

Comment: Hi Daniel, is it not possible to recover data using SESSSTARTTIME ?

Comment: It works not theoretically but in practice too. If there is an error condition occurs, which can happen in so many ways regardless what CDC method you use, you can get the LAST_UPDATED_DATE from your target table and set your variable to that timestamp and run your session.

Comment: Its possible to override the starting value of $$CDC_DT by using a parameter file for the recovery run but you'll need an audit table / file along the lines Maciejg is describing below. Either way its extra admin / testing for your recovery run. With your original strategy it will pick up where it left off once the issue has been cleared and without any extra effort / admin. Maciejg is right about when it comes to migrating but is it too much to ask people to persist mapping variables between migrations? Will save a lot of hassle

Answer (score 0):

It's a very good approach. However storing the values in a database for each run creates a quite handy audit table and can be even better. It's especially helpful during migrations - one less thing to worry about (no need to update repository variable values upon migration).

Comment: Thanks Mac, yes you are correct. But I don't have access for source schema through target schema to load session start time in to audit table using pre sql. that is the reason I choose mapping variable.